# Memory FRAM MB85RC256V data sheet interpretation

Tags: non-volatile

The FRAM (Ferroelectric Random Access Memory) Fujitsu MB85RC256V [FRAM MB85RC256V-20171207-5V1](https://www.fujitsu.com/uk/Images/MB85RC256V-20171207.pdf) says in page 8 that

> • Page Write: If additional 8 bits are continuously sent after the same
> command (*except stop condition*) as Byte Write, a page write is
> performed.

This needs no interpretation. But then, on the next page it would say:

> • Current Address Read: When the previous write or read operation
> finishes successfully *up to the stop condition* and assumes the last
> accessed address is “n”, then the address at “n+1” is read by sending
> the following command unless turning the power off.

**My question** regards interpretation of whether the English in "up to the stop condition" means the same as "except stop condition"?

I guess that not only the English needs to be understood, but also how the device works.

I believe that the two are equal, also inferred from trying to understand how the device seems to work:

1. Write 8 bits device address with R/W=0=write bit,
2. then write 16 bits FRAM memory address "n",
3. then do no stop bit because we could now
4. send an 8 bits device address with R/W=1=read bit,
5. then continue to read (first from address "n+1") as many bytes as needed,
6. until the final stop bit.

This will effectively mean that reading from an address, we need to first set the address register to one lower.

Please correct if my understanding is not 100% correct.

*Aside: I have used this FRAM in an earlier project, but via a function called i2c_master_16bit_read_reg in obsoleted library module_i2c_master (which is **so** hard to understand). The newer lib_i2c does not have that functionality, so I have to do it by extending the XC interface function there. I am using lib_i2c 5.0: [XMOS I2C Library](https://github.com/xmos/lib_i2c) (XC is sadly also obsoleted for lib_xcore and C by XMOS, but I still have an older xTIMEcomposer system up and running)*

Answer (score 0):

I guess that the next chapters of [ref1], "Random read" and "Sequential read" would show rather explicitly that the stop condition P is indeed only written when "all is done".

In other words, "up to the stop condition" does mean the same as "except stop condition".

I will correct here after I have implemented the code, should my own answer not be correct.